# Javascript array stops allowing me to add more strings after 20 objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, limit, var

I'm making a javascript game as physics project in which there is a randomly generated term on the screen and definitions placed around and you have to move your character to the correct definition before the other person. The criteria is 30 terms/concepts AND 30 matching definitions/answers; however, after 20 strings in each of my arrays it no longer allows me to add more? Is this a problem with my array or just a glitch with the javascript? I'm pretty sure the max amount of object in an array is much more than 20...

```
    var array = ['Current', 'Voltage', 'Electric Circuit', 'Conductor', 'Insulator', 'Battery', 'Series Circuit', 'Parallel Circuit', 'Electricity', 'Volts', 'Electron', 'Multimeter', 'Coulomb', 'Resistor', 'Voltage Rule', 'Amp', '6.25 * 10^n electrons', 'Energy Leaving Circuit', 'Energy Entering Circuit', 'hi'];
var array2 = ['The rate of the flow of energy', 'the difference in electric potential energy between two points per unit electric charge', 'path for electrical current to flow', 'object that permits an electric current to flow easily', 'a material that does not easily transmit energy', 'Device that converts chemical to electrical energy', 'closed circuit in which the current follows one path', 'circuit is divided into two or more paths', 'the flow of charge', 'energy per coulomb', 'charge that carries electricity through circuit', 'electrical measuring tool', 'unit of electric charge', 'reduce current flow', 'Vtotal = V1 + V2 + V3...Vn', 'coulomb per second', 'coulomb', 'sum of voltages from lightbulbs', 'sum of voltages from battery' ];
```

I added 'hi' at the end to show an example of what happens in the text editor. If it is color coded, at least on mine at the moment, the 'hi' is white while the other strings are blue and the text green. this is driving me crazy. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your editor.

Comment: Have you actually tried to run the code? You should find that it is no problem to have that many entries in an array literal.

Comment: @Saravana is right. It is most likely a problem with your text editor. JavaScript arrays are great enough to contain more than 20 strings, I swear... ^^

Comment: I use the atom IDE and have been having a lot of problems with the update but haven't been able to find anyone else having the same issues so I guess this is also a problem with the editor. The code that uses objects from array past index 19 return null. I've only ever used atom and cloud 9 which I don't like... DOES ANYONE KNOW WHY THE ATOM UPDATE RUINED EVERYTHING :(

Comment: If you need a work around just make 10 arrays 10 and join them in your init code, will prob be more readable any way.